# Flutter: Proximity Connection

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, connection

I am trying to develop a Flutter application that would allow to connect 2 users only when they are together/near each other.

I've been thinking of looking into bluetooth but is there any other technology/library/connection type that would allow this while preventing any remote connection?
Thanks a lot for your help ^^